# Are there platforms where sizeof(int) >= 128 bits

Tags: c, integer, cpu-architecture, abi

C standard says that `int` must be at least 16 bit, but doesn't say the upper bound (only `... <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= ...`.

Also, according to popular (that were/are) data models from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) there was ILP64 8/8/8 model someday, which means it had `sizeof(int) == 8 // 64 bits`.

I'm curious are there platforms that have `sizeof(int) > 8 // actually more than 64 bits`?

P.S. I tried to find similar question, but those are mostly about SSE/AVX. If it is a duplication, please, refer the answer and close this one. Thanks!

Comment: In general use, at the moment, not that I can think of. However, in order to ensure that code remains portable and trouble free it is often best to either explicitly define data sizes (common in embedded code) or allow for change in size, hence common code for determining elements in array might use `int numElements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);` where `int array[];`

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` does not have to be 8. So `sizeof(int)==1` is possible.

Comment: What do you mean with platform? Nothing stops someone from programming a C interpreter where `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT==128` (regardless of the underlying hardware).

Comment: RISC-V128 exists on paper with 128-bit integer registers, but there's no commercial use-case for it.  If anyone's ever made one, it was just to see if they could. IDK if GCC or clang can target it, and even if so, they might still use 32-bit int.  (And might have to use 64-bit long / 128-bit long long = uintptr_t if they wanted to have both uint64_t and uint128_t, unless they use `_BitInt(64)` for `uint64_t`.)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123, I agree about `sizeof(int) == 1` it is possible if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`. Under "platform" I meant some official ABI like SysV or so, but there `int` mostly defined to be `sizeof(int) == 4 // bytes` and since it defines `byte` to be 8 bits, `int` is 32 bits.

Comment: @PeterCordes, wow, interesting. I see that 128-bit now can't have wide commercial use as 64-bit architectures do, I'm just curious whether it exists or not, and also how it works, so thanks for the clue!

Comment: @PeterCordes There is no rule that only `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` are supported widths for integers. A implementation may contain additional integers with different widths than any of them. gcc has `__int128`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Right, of course they could just make up some implementation-specific type names for `[u]int64_t` if none of the base ISO C types have that width. GNU systems typically have `long` = `intptr_t`, so they'd either have to break that pattern and have 64-bit long, or invent an `__int64`, or define `int64_t` in terms of `_BitInt(64)`, or (a bad choice) not provide the optional `[u]int64_t` types.